# In R, what would be an alternative to ave(), using some function from apply family?

Tags: r, average

I am using `ave()` function to get minimum of observations with the same factor level:

```
minX = ave(x, list(factorA), FUN=min)
```

I wonder what would be an alternative using some of the functions from `apply` family? In particular, what would be an alternative to put proper result back in the dataframe? For example, lets have a small `data.frame`:

```
d = data.frame(
    x = c(2,3,3,6,5,7,8,8,9,9),
    factorA = c('a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b')
)

# function ave automatically enables proper filling of subsets
# defined by the factorA:
d$minX = ave(d$x, list(d$factorA), FUN=min)

# tapply was my first bet, but it does not produce right result:
d$minX2 = tapply(d$x, list(d$factorA), min)

# combination of split and sapply gives back the same wrong
# result as tapply:
d$minX3 = sapply(split(d$x, d$factorA), min)
```

And here are results and the differences:

```
d
# x factorA minX minX2 minX3
# 1  2       a    2     2     2
# 2  3       a    2     7     7
# 3  3       a    2     2     2
# 4  6       a    2     7     7
# 5  5       a    2     2     2
# 6  7       b    7     7     7
# 7  8       b    7     2     2
# 8  8       b    7     7     7
# 9  9       b    7     2     2
# 10 9       b    7     7     7
```

Only `ave()` returns correct minimum of `x` given `factorA`.

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest the package `dplyr`

Comment: `tapply(iris$Sepal.Length,iris$Species,min)`

Comment: have a look at `ave` .. you are using `lapply`

Comment: I have provided some additional examples. You'll see that `ave` gives back different result as compared with `tapply` or `sapply` etc. It could be that the `dplyr` has something, but I never tried.