# ave vs tapply. Is unique(ave)==tapply always? If so, why does one of them exist?

Tags: r

Consider the following -

```
set.seed(1)
x <- runif(100)
y <- sample(c('M', 'F', 'D'), 100, TRUE)
aveResult <- ave(x = x, y, FUN = sum)
tapplyResult <- tapply(x, y, sum)
aveResult <- setNames(aveResult, y)
tapplyResult
aveResult[!duplicated(names(aveResult))]
```

The results of both the functions are identical except for the length of their outputs. Furthermore, this also creates confusion (exacerbated due to recycling) as in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32403769/in-r-what-would-be-an-alternative-to-ave-using-some-function-from-apply-fami).

Is there an example where one of the functions can do something the other can't?

Comment: `ave` is used to create a column, while `tapply` summarises the output by group.  Both are useful `base R` functions.  Main advantage of `ave` is that the order of the output is not changed.  If you use `split` or `tapply` (with length of output same) the order can change based on the grouping variables

Comment: so, is `sort(unique(ave))==sort(tapply)` always true?

Comment: It depends on the functions.  For e.g. `tapply` can get a `list` output i.e. `tapply(1:10, rep(LETTERS[1:3], c(3, 3, 4)), FUN = range)`  whereas `ave` will have problems with this approach due to the length `ave(1:10, rep(LETTERS[1:3], c(3, 3, 4)), FUN = range)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ave` is a very useful `base R` function which is fast and efficient for creating new columns based on applying function by group (below is a simple example that creates a `mean` by group column using `ave`, `dplyr` and `data.table` methods).

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(grp = sample(LETTERS, 1e6, replace = TRUE), val = rnorm(1e6))
system.time(with(df1, ave(val, grp)))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.070   0.004   0.073 

library(dplyr)
system.time(df1 %>%
              group_by(grp) %>%
              mutate(new = mean(val)))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.159   0.000   0.160 

library(data.table)
system.time(setDT(df1)[, new := mean(val), by = grp])
#  user  system elapsed 
#  0.056   0.000   0.057
```

while `tapply` gives a summarised output.  One of the main advantages of `ave` is that we don't have to worry about the order of the output as it always gives output in the same order of the rows.  This can change even in some `tidyverse` functions. The question of whether the `sort`ed `unique` values of `ave` is always equal to `tapply` - it depends.  For some functions, we can get a summarised `list` output in `tapply`

```
tapply(1:10, rep(LETTERS[1:3], c(3, 3, 4)), FUN = range)
```

whereas `ave` fails here because it won't match the length of each group

```
ave(1:10, rep(LETTERS[1:3], c(3, 3, 4)), FUN = range)
```

and gives a warning

Comment: Am I to understand that `tapply` is more robust that `ave` in terms of accepting functions?

Comment: @Ameya Each function have its own pros and cons.  In general, I find `ave` a better function as we expect a vector as output but `tapply` output can vary

Answer (score 3):

Just to add one more option in this particular case: There is also `by(x, y, FUN = sum)`.

As a supplement to @akrun's excellent post, here is short break-down of the output differences between `ave`, `tapply` and `by` given OPs example data:

1. `ave(x, y, FUN = sum)` replaces `x` entries with group-summed values, where every group consists of those `x` values with the same `y` component. The return object is a vector of length `length(x)`.
2. `tapply(x, y, sum)` sums `x` values for every group; the return object is an array that has the same number of dimensions as `y` has unique groups.
3. `by(x, y, sum)` also sums `x` values for every group; the return object is a list that has the same number of entries as `y` has unique groups.

---

Perhaps another way to think about the difference between `ave` vs. `tapply`/`by` is in the context of `dplyr`'s syntax:

1. `ave` corresponds to a `group_by`+`mutate` statement:

   ```
   data.frame(x, y) %>% group_by(y) %>% mutate(x = sum(x)) %>% pull(x)
   ```
2. `tapply`/`by` corresponds to a `group_by`+`summarise` statement:

   ```
   data.frame(x, y) %>% group_by(y) %>% summarise(x = sum(x)) %>% pull(x)
   ```

---

As quite rightly emphasised by @Onyambu, `by` and `tapply` are quite different; `tapply` works on `vector`s, while `by` can take any object (typically a `data.frame`, `matrix`, etc.).

Comment: by and tapply are quite different tapply only works on vectors...by works on everything

Comment: @Onyambu Thanks for the clarification; perhaps it was not so clear from my post, but it was not my intention to claim that `by` and `tapply` were similar in general terms; only in this case does `by` and `tapply` produce equivalent results. I'll make an edit to clarify.